# LINQ Searching ordered list and appending occurence number

Tags: linq

I have the following custom class

```
public class Album
{
    public string PhotoName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and I have the following string:

```
@"photo.jpg, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:08:15
john.png, London, 2015-06-20 15:13:22
myFriends.png, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:07:13
Eiffel.jpg, Paris, 2015-07-23 08:03:02
pisatower.jpg, Paris, 2015-07-22 23:59:59
BOB.jpg, London, 2015-08-05 00:02:03"
```

and I need to write a function that will append the order number beside the Location based on the timestamp thus the resulting StringBuilder must be

```
Warsaw01.jpg
London01.jpg
Warsaw02.jpg
Paris01.jpg
Paris02.jpg
London02.jpg
```

**What I have done so far?**

I have a List of that type that I sorted by Location then by DateTime

```
List<Album> SortedList = list
  .OrderBy(o => o.Location)
  .ThenBy(o => o.DateTime)
  .ToList();
```

now I need to have a StringBuilder that will append the index number beside the location.

This is my complete method with the part and I am stuck on how should I search the ordered list. Question is: how can I write the LINQ for searching through the list?:

```
public static string Solution(string S)
    {
        string[] group = S.Split("\r\n");
        List<Album> list = new List<Album>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //added each line of the string to list
        foreach (string g in group)
        {
            string[] album = g.Split(',');
            Album a = new Album();
            a.PhotoName = album[0];
            a.Location = album[1];
            a.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(album[2]);
            list.Add(a);
        }

    //ordered the list
        List<Album> SortedList = list.OrderBy(o => o.Location).ThenBy(o => o.DateTime).ToList();

        //then foreach line, append index number by searching through the list
        foreach (string g in group)
        {
            string[] album = g.Split(',');
            Album a = new Album();
            a.PhotoName = album[0];
            string[] photodetails = a.PhotoName.Split('.');
            a.Location = album[1];
            a.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(album[2]);

           //this is the part where I must figure out how to build the string. I am stuck here

           // var query = SortedList.IndexOf(list.SingleOrDefault(i => i.DateTime == a.DateTime));

            sb.AppendLine(a.Location + query + "." + photodetails[1]);

        }

        string res = sb.ToString();
        return res;
    }
```

Appreciate the responses.

**Update** Warsaw2 must appear before Warsaw1 since the timestamp of Warsaw2 is later than Warsaw1

```
Warsaw02.jpg
London01.jpg
Warsaw01.jpg
Paris01.jpg
Paris02.jpg
London02.jpg
```

Comment: What is the expected result? can you post it for that specific input?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I have stated it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just added a order in the Album class

```
  public class Album
{
    public string PhotoName { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public static string Solution(string S)
    {
        string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
        string[] group = S.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
        List<Album> list = new List<Album>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //added each line of the string to list
        for (int i = 0; i < group.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] album = group[i].Split(',');
            Album a = new Album();
            a.PhotoName = album[0];
            a.Location = album[1];
            a.DateTime = DateTime.Parse(album[2]);
            a.Order = i;
            list.Add(a);
        }

        //ordered the list
        var groupedByLocation = list.GroupBy(o => o.Location).ToList();


        for (int i = 0; i < groupedByLocation.Count; i++)
        {
            int indexValue = 01;
            foreach (var item in groupedByLocation[i])
            {
                item.PhotoName = string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", groupedByLocation[i].Key, indexValue);
                indexValue++;
            }
        }

        //then foreach line, append index number by searching through the list
        var locations = groupedByLocation
                        .SelectMany(g => g.Select(h => h))
                        .ToList()
                        .OrderBy(y => y.Order)
                        .Select(g => g.PhotoName);

        return string.Join("\r\n", locations);
    }
```

Comment: Up for this. Very helpful.

Comment: This is very basic form you need to improve the code before using in production

Comment: Hold on, sorry. Warsaw2 must be first to appear before Warsaw1 since the timestamp on the first Warsaw line is later than the third.

Comment: just updated this by adding an OrderBy before GroupBy: var groupedByLocation = list.OrderBy(o=>o.DateTime).GroupBy(o => o.Location).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun - an alternative approach:

For the task at hand, there's no need to have an `Album` class, a `list` and two loops.

We can go over the lines once, and use a `dictionary` to hold the counters for us.

```
class PhotoLocationsCounter
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> locationsCounter = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public string GetLocationsWithCounters(string source)
    {
        string[] lines = source.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var locations = lines.Select(this.LineToLocationWithCounter);

        return string.Join("\n", locations);
    }

    private string LineToLocationWithCounter(string line)
    {
        string[] album = line.Split(',');
        var location = album[1].Trim();
        var ext = album[0].Split('.')[1];
        var counter = this.GetAndIncreaseLocationCounter(location);
        return $"{location}{counter.ToString("D2")}.{ext}";
    }

    private int GetAndIncreaseLocationCounter(string location)
    {
        if (!this.locationsCounter.TryGetValue(location, out int counter))
        {
            this.locationsCounter.Add(location, 0);
        }
        return ++this.locationsCounter[location];
    }
}
```

And you call it:

```
string data = @"photo.jpg, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:08:15
john.png, London, 2015-06-20 15:13:22
myFriends.png, Warsaw, 2013-09-05 14:07:13
Eiffel.jpg, Paris, 2015-07-23 08:03:02
pisatower.jpg, Paris, 2015-07-22 23:59:59
BOB.jpg, London, 2015-08-05 00:02:03";
var locations = new PhotoLocationsCounter().GetLocationsWithCounters(data);
```

Comment: I updated my expected result since it must be ordered by DateTime, after you post this. Just don't know if result will be the same if I try this, but I will try